# Vue 2 + Storybook: document events with Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, storybook

In a Vue 2 project using Storybook, a component is using composition API and emits an event:

```
export default Vue.extend({
   setup(_, { emit }) {
      //some code
      emit('myEvent');
   }
});
```

I can't find a way to document this myEvent emited event. All of the examples from the [Vue Styleguidist](https://vue-styleguidist.github.io/docs/Documenting.html#events) are with the Option API.
I would like to add this event to an event' s section in the storybook page, something like

[image]

Anyone knows if this is possible?
I am using storybook/vue 6.5.8.